# Justifications for why God cares about small Halakhic minutiae

Tags: halacha

How do we explain why God cares about how we perform small, seemingly insignificant details (e.g. alternating hands when washing, right shoe before left) of life? Do any Rishonim or Acharonim, rationalist or more mystical, deal with this question? Thank you